# CMake- what is the difference between 'target_link_options(.. -lgcov)' and 'target_link_libraries(...gcov)'?

Tags: c++, cmake, gcov

I'm trying to build a library with code coverage enabled like so:

```
    add_library(my_library my_lib.cpp)
    target_compile_options(my_library PRIVATE --coverage)
    target_link_options(my_library PRIVATE -lgcov)
```

and then later I have some tests for the library:

```
    add_executable(my_test my_test.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(my_test my_library)
```

However I get link errors when building the tests-

```
libmy_library.a(my_lib.cpp.o): In function `_GLOBAL__sub_I_00100_0__ZN7myClass10returnTrueEv':
my_lib.cpp:(.text+0x2f): undefined reference to `__gcov_init'
libmy_library.a(my_lib.cpp.o): In function `_GLOBAL__sub_D_00100_1__ZN7myClass10returnTrueEv':
my_lib.cpp:(.text+0x3a): undefined reference to `__gcov_exit'
libmy_library.a(my_lib.cpp.o):(.data.rel+0x20): undefined reference to `__gcov_merge_add'
```

If instead of using `target_link_options` I use `target_link_libraries` -

```
    target_link_libraries(my_library PRIVATE gcov)
```

then I don't get the errors.

What's the reason for the difference in behaviour? I thought that `target_link_libraries(my_library PRIVATE gcov)` would be equivalent to `target_link_options(my_library PRIVATE -lgcov)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is right there, in the [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_options.html):

> Note This command cannot be used to add options for static library
> targets, since they do not use a linker. To add archiver or MSVC
> librarian flags, see the STATIC_LIBRARY_OPTIONS target property.